# Haskell displays a parse error

Tags: haskell, syntax, syntax-error

Can someone please help me? I am trying to run the `average` function but I get an error that reads "(parse error) on input '::'" for this code:

```
sum` :: [Int] -> Int
sum` [] = 0
sum` (x:xs) = x + sum` xs

length` :: [a] -> Int
length` [] = 0
length` (x:xs) = 1 + length` xs

average :: [Int] -> Rational
average [] = error "empty list"
average xs = toRational (sum xs) / toRational(length xs)
```

Many thanks

Comment: I don't think you can use back ticks (```), try using single quotes (`'`)

Comment: @JosephYoung since your comment solved the problem, can you post it as an answer so it can be accepted?

Answer (score 3):

As per the advice in the comments, I have moved my comment to an answer:

I don't think you can use back ticks (`` ` ``), try using single quotes (`'`)

So it'd be:

```
sum' :: [Int] -> Int
sum' [] = 0
sum' (x:xs) = x + sum' xs

length' :: [a] -> Int
length' [] = 0
length' (x:xs) = 1 + length' xs

average :: [Int] -> Rational
average [] = error "empty list"
average xs = toRational (sum xs) / toRational(length xs)
```